# Can I get idfa without calling AppTrackingTransparency frameworks using xcode12 on ios14

Tags: ios, apptrackingtransparency

I use Xcode 12 to compile and use the following code to get IDFA on iOS 13.4 devices.

```
if ASIdentifierManager.shared().isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled {
    let idfa = ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
}
```

But using the same code, no IDFA can be obtained without calling ATT on an iOS 14 device.

Apple confirmed that we can be on Xcode 12 and not call the App Transparency at all until it's required.

Is this result correct?

Comment: It seems to be inconsistent.  I have two phones running iOS 14.4.  On one I get `.denied` for tracking and an IDFA of 0.  On the other phone I get `.notDetermined` and a value for the IDFA.  The app doesn't ask for tracking permission.

Comment: I tried on another phone with iOS 14.3 and it also gets `.denied`.  I have seen a few other threads that indicate this is an issue with 14.3. The 14.4 phone with the problem was previously on 14.3. The 14.4 phone that works was previously on 14.2 (It also worked on 14.2).  Perhaps if a device has ever been on 14.3 it is now "broken" - If I ask for tracking permission the formerly 14.3 phone doesn't display the dialog while the other one does